# How can i move the data into Tab Screens in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to move data:

```
  navigation.navigate('Statistics', {wordsInText})
```

But the screen swaps into Statistic screen. How can i prohibit it?
Like only move data, withot swapping the screen

Comment: Is `Statistics` a child component in the screen from which you are currently trying to navigate?

Comment: The structure is in Tab Navigator: Statistics, Train, Profile. I need to move on data from screen Train into statistics, without moving screens

Comment: It's like pass parametrs a from one screen to another, but without swapping the screen

Comment: How do I update navigation params, without navigating to screen